# Cannot build Flutter app on iOS emulator or physical device - works fine on Android though

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio

I've returned to Android Studio & Flutter after some time away and I've tried to build my app and I get the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
```

Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `webview_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A Flutter
  A url_launcher
  A webview_flutter

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing Flutter (1.0.0)

-> Installing url_launcher (0.0.1)

-> Installing webview_flutter (0.0.1)
  - Running pre install hooks
[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (/Users/ashleywhitehair/AndroidStudioProjects/cvonline-master/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework)

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:74:in `each_key'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:74:in `block in verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:73:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:73:in `verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/target_validator.rb:38:in `validate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:595:in `validate_targets'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your whole pod file with the text below.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'testing_gowtham' do

use_frameworks!


pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
end
```

**If solution 1 is not working then you can also try the solution 2**

> `platform :ios, '9.0'` is working...I simply removed **#** this

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me and I get the same error. Thank you for postings though.